# If command is being executed in wrong channel return

Tags: discord.js

If the command was executed in wrong channel bot should detect it and `return message.reply("wrong channel")`

With code below, I want to make `bots channel` be the main channel for a bot to run its commands

Code:

```
if(!message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "bots")) return message.reply("wrong channel")
```

Code is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find an issue and fix it.

Old code:

```
if(!message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "bots")) return message.reply("wrong channel")
```

New Code:

```
  var ChannelName = message.channel.name
  if(ChannelName !== "bots") return message.reply("wrong channel")
```

Hopefully this helps.